# Dice roll sum game

Tags: python

Okay, I'm at a loss. I am trying to make a game where you roll a die as many times as you like, but if the sum of your rolls is greater than or equal to 14, you lose. (note I'm pretty new to programing, so sorry if it's pretty bad.) The issue is that the code keeps on running, as in it keeps on asking the user for input" even if the sum of "your_list" is greater than 14.

```
import random
your_list = []


def dice_simulate():
    number = random.randint(1,6)
    print(number)
    while(1):
       flag = str(input("Do you want to dice it up again:Enter 1 and if not enter    0"))
       if flag == '1':
         number = random.randint(1,6)
         your_list.append(number)
         print(number)
         print (your_list)
       elif sum(your_list) >= 14:
         print ('you lose')
       else:
         print("ending the game")
         return

dice_simulate()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I can't figure this out"—how is the code you're showing us failing, specifically? Please read [ask].

Comment: can you elaborate, I'm new to coding. sorry.

Comment: @JakobGoodfriend You need to specify what your code does, what you expect it to do, and show what you have tried to fix your problem. [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) Also good to follow the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953)

Comment: Also, there is no need to cast `str()` on `input` as `input` always returns a `str`.

Comment: I'm going to guess at your problem since it isn't very clear: you are only checking whether the sum of the list is greater than or equal to 14 if the user _doesn't_ enter `1` (`elif` is short for "_else_ if"). I'm guessing maybe you want to do that even if they enter `1`, so they can lose when they roll the die?

Comment: sorry its unclear, to clarify, if you enter 1, it will roll and that roll gets sent to the list you_list, and 0 will mean u want to end the game. What I'm trying to figure out is how to make the game end if the sum of your_list is equal to or greater than 14.

Comment: @JakobGoodfriend, we are asking for a specific problem definition. The one I've guessed at (and answered) in my previous comment would be something like, "The user can keep pressing 1 over and over forever, even if the total in the list goes over 14. But it's supposed to stop and tell the user they lost as soon as the total goes over 14."

Answer (score 0):

Add the condition for winning and `return` in this case. Also, add `return` to the condition where you lose.

Additional changes to improve the code:

- Remove the useless first dice roll (which does not get counted in your case).
- Declare `your_list` in the smallest scope possible (here, inside the function).
- Improve the prompt.

```
import random

def dice_simulate():
    your_list = []
    while True:
       flag = str(input("Roll the dice (y/n)? "))
       if flag == 'y':
         number = random.randint(1,6)
         your_list.append(number)
         print(number)
         print (your_list)
         list_sum = sum(your_list)
         if list_sum > 14:
             print ('you lose')
             return
         elif list_sum == 14:
             print ('you win')
             return
       else:
         print("ending the game")
         return

dice_simulate()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm pretty new and was at a genuine loss.

Comment: Please, do get rid of the `while(1):` line. That's not a good idiom to teach, Python statements like `while` do not need parentheses, and `while` is not a function. Use `while True:`, instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you for the suggestion to use a more Pythonic `while True`. Updated the answer.